# No tab completion with asterisk *

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I am not able to tab complete from the command line in gnome-terminal when I have an asterisk in the command line. Default shell is bash, using gnome-terminal. For example,

This works to copy a single file into a dir **using tab-completion on the `~/files/` directory**:

```
cp ~/file1 ~/files/
```

However this **does not** work using tab completion on the directory when I want to copy multiple files into a dir (I have to manually type out or paste `~/files/`):

```
cp ~/file* ~/files/
```

(Assuming there exist the files `file1`, `file2`, `file3` & `file4`)

And this **does tab complete the directory** (and works as I would expect regex to work, copying all of those files into `~/files/`):

```
cp ~/file?* ~/files/
```

So I do have a workaround. But I know I have had this working before without having to use the `?` and I'm not exactly sure how or when I lost it. As a heavy command line user I've been living with it, but it's been relatively annoying lately.

EDIT1+:

Output of `$ compopt cp`

```
compopt +o bashdefault +o default +o dirnames +o filenames +o nospace +o plusdirs cp
```

Output of `$ set -x` then `$ cp ~/file* ~/file<tab>`

```
+ ((  COMP_CWORD += 1  ))
+ COMP_WORDS=(cp -i ${COMP_WORDS[@]:1})
+ ((  COMP_POINT -= 17  ))
+ COMP_LINE='cp -i ./file* ./file'
+ ((  COMP_POINT += 20  ))
+ _longopt
+ local cur prev words cword split
+ _init_completion -s
+ local exclude= flag outx errx inx OPTIND=1
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ case $flag in
+ split=false
+ exclude+==
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ COMPREPLY=()
+ local 'redir=@(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)'
+ _get_comp_words_by_ref -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ local exclude flag i OPTIND=1
+ words=()
+ local cur cword words
+ upargs=()
+ upvars=()
+ local upargs upvars vcur vcword vprev vwords
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ case $flag in
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ [[ 6 -ge 3 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcur=cur
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 4 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vprev=prev
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 5 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vwords=words
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 6 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcword=cword
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 7 ]]
+ __get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref '=<>&' words cword cur
+ words=()
+ local cword words
+ __reassemble_comp_words_by_ref '=<>&' words cword
+ local exclude i j line ref
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ eval cword=3
++ cword=3
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ line='cp -i ./file* ./file'
+ (( i=0, j=0 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+ ref='words[0]'
+ eval 'words[0]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[0]=cp
+ line=' -i ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 0 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 1 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -i == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[1]'
+ eval 'words[1]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[1]=-i
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 1 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 2 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./file1 == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[2]'
+ eval 'words[2]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[2]=./file1
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 2 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 3 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./file2 == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[3]'
+ eval 'words[3]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[3]=./file2
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 3 == 3 ]]
+ eval cword=3
++ cword=3
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 4 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./file3 == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[4]'
+ eval 'words[4]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[4]=./file3
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 4 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 5 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./file4 == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[5]'
+ eval 'words[5]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[5]=./file4
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 5 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 6 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./files == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[6]'
+ eval 'words[6]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[6]=./files
+ line=' ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 6 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 7 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ./file == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[7]'
+ eval 'words[7]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[7]=./file
+ line='* ./file'
+ [[ 7 == 3 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 8 == 3 ]]
+ local i cur index=20 'lead=cp -i ./file* ./file'
+ [[ 20 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -n cp -i ./file* ./file ]]
+ [[ -n cp-i./file*./file ]]
+ cur='cp -i ./file* ./file'
+ (( i = 0 ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 20 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ cp != \c\p ]]
+ [[ 0 -lt 3 ]]
+ local old_size=20
+ cur=' -i ./file* ./file'
+ local new_size=18
+ index=18
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 18 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[  - != \-\i ]]
+ cur='-i ./file* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 17 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ -i != \-\i ]]
+ [[ 1 -lt 3 ]]
+ local old_size=17
+ cur=' ./file* ./file'
+ local new_size=15
+ index=15
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 15 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[  ./file != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='./file* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 14 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ ./file* != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='/file* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 13 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ /file*  != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='file* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 12 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ file* . != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='ile* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 11 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ ile* ./ != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='le* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 10 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ le* ./f != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='e* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 9 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ e* ./fi != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur='* ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 8 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ * ./fil != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur=' ./file'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 7 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[  ./file != \.\/\f\i\l\e\1 ]]
+ cur=./file
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 6 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ 2 -lt 3 ]]
+ local old_size=6
+ cur=./file
+ local new_size=6
+ index=6
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 6 -ge 7 ]]
+ [[ 3 -lt 3 ]]
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ -n ./file ]]
+ [[ ! -n ./file ]]
+ [[ 6 -lt 0 ]]
+ local words cword cur
+ _upvars -a8 words cp -i ./file1 ./file2 ./file3 ./file4 ./files ./file -v cword 3 -v cur ./file
+ ((  16  ))
+ ((  16  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 8 ]]
+ printf %d 8
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:8}")'
++ words=("${@:3:8}")
+ shift 10
+ ((  6  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=3
+ shift 3
+ ((  3  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur=./file
+ shift 3
+ ((  0  ))
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcur")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcur "$cur")
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcword")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcword "$cword")
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ [[ 3 -ge 1 ]]
+ upvars+=("$vprev")
+ upargs+=(-v $vprev "${words[cword - 1]}")
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ upvars+=("$vwords")
+ upargs+=(-a${#words[@]} $vwords "${words[@]}")
+ ((  4  ))
+ local cur cword prev words
+ _upvars -v cur ./file -v cword 3 -v prev ./file1 -a8 words cp -i ./file1 ./file2 ./file3 ./file4 ./files ./file
+ ((  19  ))
+ ((  19  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur=./file
+ shift 3
+ ((  16  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=3
+ shift 3
+ ((  13  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ unset -v prev
+ eval 'prev="$3"'
++ prev=./file1
+ shift 3
+ ((  10  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 8 ]]
+ printf %d 8
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:8}")'
++ words=("${@:3:8}")
+ shift 10
+ ((  0  ))
+ _variables
+ [[ ./file =~ ^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]
+ return 1
+ [[ ./file == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ [[ ./file1 == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&) ]]
+ local i skip
+ (( i=1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ -i == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=2
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./file1 == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=3
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./file2 == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=4
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./file3 == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=5
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./file4 == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=6
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./files == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=7
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ ./file == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=8
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 8 ))
+ [[ 3 -le 0 ]]
+ prev=./file1
+ [[ -n false ]]
+ _split_longopt
+ [[ ./file == --?*=* ]]
+ return 1
+ return 0
+ case "${prev,,}" in
+ false
+ [[ ./file == -* ]]
+ [[ '' == @(mk|rm)dir ]]
+ _filedir
+ local i 'IFS=
' xspec
+ _tilde ./file
+ local result=0
+ [[ ./file == \~* ]]
+ return 0
+ local -a toks
+ local quoted x tmp
+ _quote_readline_by_ref ./file quoted
+ '[' -z ./file ']'
+ [[ ./file == \'* ]]
+ [[ ./file == \~* ]]
+ printf -v quoted %q ./file
+ [[ ./file == *\\* ]]
+ [[ ./file == \$* ]]
++ compgen -d -- ./file
+ x=./files
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ [[ '' != -d ]]
+ xspec=
++ compgen -f -X '' -- ./file
+ x='./file2
./file3
./files
./file1
./file4'
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ 6 -ne 0 ]]
+ compopt -o filenames
+ COMPREPLY+=("${toks[@]}")
```

END EDIT1-

---

I have not changed my `/etc/inputrc` or added an `~/.inputrc`.

The package `bash-completion` is installed.

I have uncommented in my `.bashrc` the section that enables tab-completion quite a long time ago (it works well in all other instances and this problem I now have WAS working before).

It does not work in any of the terminals I have installed in my system (Ubuntu 14.04). And in case someone is thinking this, no it's not a valid solution to re-install Ubuntu.  :)

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `compopt cp`. Also, try `set -x`, then do `cp file* ~/file<tab>`.  The output might be informative.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What a great first question!

Comment: Can you think of anything else you changed?  I tried it without `?` and it works fine for me.  My only other thought was the `.bashrc` but you already looked into that...

Comment: @Dorian - Would you mind posting the output of your `set -x` `cp ./file* ./file<tab>` somehow? (or maybe message me, I'm not sure how it works best on these boards) I might be able to diff the 2 outputs and come up with something. If I do find something, of course I'll post back results.

Comment: Have you tried creating another user account to see if it also has the same problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should test gobbing out in a shell that doesn't load your profile or rc files. Eg: `env -i bash --noprofile --norc`. If everything works after that, then you can use process of elimination to determine what lines of your bash configuration files are to blame. Otherwise, you have something weird going on.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to comment out a function I had added to my `~/.bashrc`. The function was used to do some funky tab-completion regarding alias's. (Found it on the interwebs, I won't get into it here)

I used justsomeguy's suggestion to do `env -i bash --noprofile --norc`. And completions worked normally.

I then did `env -i bash --norc` -- completions still normal.

Then did `env -i bash` and the completions were failing again. So I concluded that the problem was in my `~/.bashrc` and troubleshot from there.

Thanks for the help!